# Using Web Api in a MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to use/call my Web API methods inside a MVC controller? 
I have a Web Api to use in mobile and others plattaforms and I´m developing a .NET Mvc Website. 
Does that architecture makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, there are two tidy ways to approach this: either call the WebAPI methods from the page itself using Javscript, or move the internal logic of those methods to a separate place where your MVC controllers and WebAPI can both call it at will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible although if you're expecting to consume your API from a number of different clients I would suggest you create your API as a separate application that can then be managed/scaled accordingly.

Essentially you are referring to "dog-fooding" your own API, making your own web application no different to any other client.

We do something similar and have our MVC application call our API (using `HttpClient`). We also have a lot of client side code within the same application that calls the API directly using CORS.

We've had this architecture running in production for 2 years now without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is How I call my Web API controller from MVC controller:

```
public class invoiceController : ApiController
    {
        private myEntities db = new db1Entities();

        // GET api/invoices
        public IQueryable<invoices> Getinvoices()
        {
            return db.invoices;
        }
}
```

inside separate MVC controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowInvoices()
{
  var webApi = new invoicesController();
  //this must return strongly typed object
  var myarray = webApi.Getinvoices(); 
  return View(myarray);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good approach. If you want to share logic between MVC and Web API in the *same* application, move it into a separate class; don't invoke your Web API controller from MVC.